# Select list with an option of 0 not abiding to default value

Tags: c#, html, razor, razor-pages

So I have a select list with a fairly trival problem,

```
<div>
    <label>Label Title:<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <select class="form-select" asp-for="ModelProperty">
        <option selected disabled> </option>
        @for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
        {
            <option value="@i">@i</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

My issue is on form load the selected default value will go to 0, even though im using the selected tag on a blank value, how would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the property that you are binding the select list to nullable:

```
public int? ModelProperty { get; set; }
```

The select tag helper will set the selected option to the value of the property. The default for a non-nullable `int` is `0`. If the property doesn't have a value, the hard-coded selected option will be honoured.

If the associated form field is mandatory, add a `[Required]` attribute to the property:

```
[Required]
public int? ModelProperty { get; set; }
```